# Организация кросс-доменного запроса.

Tags: javascript, cross-origin

Привет. Есть сервер denwer. Создал два хоста :
http://localhost/test/
http://localhost/test2/

**http://localhost/test/index.html**

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost/test2/1.php',
    crossDomain: true,
    data: '{"some":"json"}',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        var value = responseData.someKey;
    },
    error: function (responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('POST failed.');
    }
});
```

**localhost/test2/1.php**

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
function xmlrpc_server_output($xml) {
    $xml = '<?xml version="1.0"?>'."\n". $xml;
    header('Connection: close');
    header('Content-Length: '. strlen($xml));
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    header('Date: '. date('r'));
    // $xml = str_replace("\n", " ", $xml); 

    echo $xml;
    exit;
}
$xml='<a><b>fe</b></a>';
xmlrpc_server_output($xml);
```

В консоли вижу ответ от сайта [image]

Проблема что срабатывает  alert('POST failed.'); .В чем причина?

UPD: 
Создал 2 хоста

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
  DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/test" 
  ServerName "dev.megalot.local" 
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80> 
  DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/test2" 
  ServerName "dev2.megalot.local" 
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: А в чем вопрос?

Comment: оновил....

Comment: Ну кроссдоменного запроса как такого здесь нет, домен один - `http://localhost`. Ошибка у вас из-за этого:

    dataType: 'json'

Приходит-то xml, который парсер json отказывается парсить.

Comment: Исправил ошибку dataType ...Callback  сработал. Теперь нужно организовать кроссдоменный ..

Comment: Дайте вывод console.log(responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) на ошибке

Comment: Может, из-за header('Connection: close') ?

Comment: Всем спасибо получилось....